# Find Word and add new line

Tags: r

hello how i can find a Word and add new line

```
data <- c("ran hi i man and bla bla ran hi i man and bla bla ran hi i man and bla bla ran hi i man and bla bla ran hi i man and bla bla")
```

i try this but dont know how :X

str_replace(data,"(ran)","\n")

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for ?

```
stringr::str_replace(data,"(man)","\\1\n")
```

which can be written in base R as well :

```
gsub('(man)', '\\1\n', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to substitute the word with the new line, then your code works. If you want to keep the word and add a new line afterwards, use Ronak's code. But neither is actually going to print a new line, as that's not how R's vectors work, what you can do to print those "\n" as new lines is use `cat` function:

```
cat(stringr::str_replace(data,"(man)","\\1\n"), sep="\n")
```

Or

```
cat(stringr::str_replace(data,"(man)","\n"), sep="\n")
```

Obs: the `sep="\n"` breaks the line after every element in `data`. The output is:

```
> cat(stringr::str_replace(data,"(man)","\n"), sep="\n")
Ran hi i 
 and bla bla
and want bla bla thxx
Dan hello i want to fly
thxx all
David hello i want to fly
thxx all
Yanis hello i want to fly
thxx all
Ran hello i want to fly
thxx all
Yanis hello i want to fly
thxx all
David hello i want to fly
thxx all
Yanis hello i want to fly
thxx all
```

I suggest using `"(man )"` as your pattern to get rid of that space before  `and bla bla`.

Comment: i edit cat(stringr::str_replace(data,"(man)","\n")) i want this multiply in text ------- edit :X i stupid cat(stringr::str_replace_all(data,"(ran)","\n")) thxx

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept my answer to mark the post as solved :). Also, read this tips on how to ask good questions because your was a little confuse: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and how save it into data again ? data <- cat(stringr::str_replace_all(data,"(ran)","\n ran"))

Comment: Yes, that works. But check the suggestions i made, i think `data <- cat(stringr::str_replace_all(data,"(ran )","\n ran"), sep="\n")` will work better for you.

Comment: data <- cat(stringr::str_replace_all(data,"(ran )","\n ran"), sep="\n") its empty

Comment: Oh sorry, actually it doesn't work. `cat` is only for visualization, if you want to save it as a variable it's best to use `strsplit`: `data <- unlist(strsplit(data, "ran"))`. When `"ran"` is in the beginning of an element, it'll create a empty `""` element. To get rid of those, do `data <- data[-which(data=="")]`.

Comment: Sorry for the time: X I just want to keep the word = "ran" in the text

Comment: i can mybe the lng way this dtdtdtasdas <- str_replace_all(data,"(ran)","ran newwline") dtdtdtasdas <- unlist(strsplit(dtdtdtasdas, "newwline"))

Comment: Dont worry :). Yes, you can do it that way, which is easier to understand what's going on. A other option is `data <- unlist(strsplit(data, "?<=ran"))`, the `?<=` part is a special matching condition that i didn't took the time to understand why works, but it is cleaner at least.

Answer (score 0):

you don't say what the problem is.

with your data, i run this line

```
library(stringr)
data_oneword <- str_replace_all(data, "hello", "hello\n")
```

and get what you seem to be asking for

```
 [1] "Ran hi i man and bla bla"    "and want bla bla thxx"       "Dan hello\n i want to fly"  
 [4] "thxx all"                    "David hello\n i want to fly" "thxx all"                   
 [7] "Yanis hello\n i want to fly" "thxx all"                    "Ran hello\n i want to fly"  
[10] "thxx all"                    "Yanis hello\n i want to fly" "thxx all"                   
[13] "David hello\n i want to fly" "thxx all"                    "Yanis hello\n i want to fly"
[16] "thxx all"
```

Comment: i want newline its not new line its change the word from "hello" to "hello\n"

Comment: It will add a new line when you render it.